# Windows - do not require password (GPO)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-authentication

I'm setting up a small Active Directory installation for a company where they gave me the following requirement:

While users should enter a password to logon in the morning, it is not required that they do so during the day, or at least not after only a short idle time.

I found many internet articles on how to reduce idle time but in my understanding they cannot be applied to the opposite.

My questions:

1. Is there a possibility to increase idle time before requesting a Password to, say, 1 hour? How to set it up?
2. Is there a possibility to define periods of time when a password is not needed at all? Or the other way round, define times when a password is needed?

If you know of another helpful solution as an alternative to or building on the above, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "idle time" as it relates to a user account. A user will never need to re-enter their password if they've been idle for some period of time. You may be thinking of a screensaver that locks a users workstation and requires a password to unlock but that isn't enabled by default. You might also be thinking about idle RDSH session management, but it isn't apparent from your question that this is what you're referring to.

So you can tell your client that there's no such thing as "idle time" and that they don't need to be concerned about users having to re-enter a password if they've been idle for some period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Idle time might be the wrong expression, then. But this is not a theoretical question, it's a running system (I set up) and users are being locked out after a certain time of inactivity, though I never defined anything like that and there is no screensaver. Not sure it matters but the clients are Win10.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the problem. How are they being locked out?

Comment: They are sent back to the switch user screen and have to click on their username to log back in which means they have to reenter the password.

Comment: That sounds like the screensaver on each workstation is enabled. You'll need to go to each workstation and check it. There's no mechanism in AD to log out or lock a user from their workstation when the user is idle.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. If there should be no screensaver, then all that is left as a culprit is the standbymode.